# why doesn't the keys ` + a give me à?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key it says that the keys  ` + a should give me à but apparently its not working. so basically I'm wondering which computer was the wikipedia article targeted at?

Comment: It's not a *computer* that it's targeted at. It's a keyboard layout.

Comment: @Mark Szymanski so it actually works on windows?

Comment: @Pacerier: AFAIK it does. I don't use Windows so I can't say for sure.

Comment: @Mark Szymanski so it actually works on mac?

Comment: @Pacerier Yes it does àpparently. You don't even say which keyboard layout you have, which would make it easier to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: @Pacerier: Yes, it does work on OS X. If you set your keyboard layout to "US International" you can use dead keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work on any system that is using a **U.S. International** keyboard layout. Go into your keyboard settings and choose that layout.

Comment: It **also works on non-U.S. keyboard layouts**, you just probably have to press `Shift` before `, for example on German layouts.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the program.

E.g. it works on Wordpad, but not on Notepad. Try the former.

---

Edit: If you're using XP, try going to Control Panel --> Regional and Language Options --> Advanced and checking `Extend support of advanced text services to all programs`, and seeing if that helps.

Comment: Works fine on both here...

Comment: @Ignacio: Weird, it doesn't for me. You reckon it has anything to do with the "Extend text services to all programs" setting?

Comment: Possibly. I do have that enabled here.

Comment: I don't have the extend support of advanced text services in windows vista home premium